# How to reintegrate with automatic merge (merge-tracking) in TortoiseSVN 1.8

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-reintegrate, merge-tracking

I've read both [these release notes for SVN 1.8](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#auto-reintegrate) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444634/tortoisesvn-subversion-1-8-merge-no-more-reintegrate-a-branch-option) concerning reintegration of a branch with SVN 1.8.

My questions, which I couldn't find an answer to, is the following:

Is there any difference between choosing

1. `all revisions`
2. `specific range` together with an empty box

in the Tortoise Merge-Dialogue when reintegrating a branch into the trunk?

Does Turtoise in either case use an automatic merge with merge-tracking? How can I verify that?

Comment: See the answer about differences in merges in TortoiseSVN 1.7 vs 1.8 http://stackoverflow.com/a/25525371/761095

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that doesn't answer my question. I know the basic differences between the old and the new way of reintegration in SVN (with and without --reintegrate option).
What I want to know is the difference between the Turtoise settings stated above. I can't find anything about this in your linked answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html), checking "all revisions" is the same as checking "specific range" and leaving an empty box.  In both cases, an automatic merge is used:

> If you leave the range of revisions empty or have the radio button *all revisions* checked, then Subversion merges all not-yet merged revisions. This is known as a reintegrate or automatic merge.

Comment: Oops, I totally missed that sentence in the documentation. Thanks for pointing me to it.